# Python multiprocessing: Call python script and pass different argument to every process/execution

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a (large and complex) python script consisting of several classes which generates time series for a lot of variables. Each model run is randomly different from the others (if I don't set random seed). I have to run the model several times in parallel and I want to have control over the random seed for every model run/process.

The caller for the script looks like this so far:

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool

n_cores = 2
n_iterations = 6

def run_process(process):
    os.system('python mymodel.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(n_cores)
    p.map(run_process, range(n_iterations))
```

And I need something like this:

```
import os                                                                       
from multiprocessing import Pool
import random as rd

list_seeds = list(range(-10, 10, 1))
n_cores = 2
n_iterations = len(list_seeds)
mycounter = 0

def run_process(process):
    rd.seed(list_seeds[mycounter])
    mycounter += 1
    os.system('python mymodel.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool(n_cores)
    p.map(run_process, range(n_iterations))
```

I cannot set the random seed of the called script in this way (or pass any other argument for that matter). Please show me the way how to achieve this (if there is one), the discussions/questions I found so far were not that helpful/confusing to me...

Thanks!

Edit:
Is it a bad idea anyway to call another script like this? And like this, I guess it is impossible to pass any arguments. What I could try: define a function, whichs runs mymodel in the same script, and give this function to multiprocessing with the iterable as the argument. Anybody tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `partial` to transport the seed-list to the process function:

```
def run_process(list_seeds, iteration):
    rd.seed(list_seeds[iteration])
    os.system('python mymodel.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from functools import partial
    func_to_multiprocess = partial(run_process, list_seeds)
    p = Pool(n_cores)
    p.map(func_to_multiprocess , range(n_iterations))
```

What I don't understand however, why do you pass process to `run_process()`?

Comment: You meant: p.map(func_to_multiprosess, range(n_iterations)) ?? I tried it like this, it does not control the seed in the process?!

Comment: Yes, I meant that

Answer (score 0):

You could use [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) to pass multiple arguments so that you can keep track of your seeds outside your worker functions.

```
import random
from multiprocessing import Pool

def run_process(task_nr,seed):
    result = random.Random(seed).random()
    print ('Task number {} resulted in: {}'.format(task_nr,result))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_cores = 2
    n_iterations = 6

    # generate a list of tasks
    tasks = range(n_iterations+1)
    # determine seeds
    seeds = [1,1,1,2,2,3]
    # create pool with 2 processes
    p = Pool(processes=n_cores)
    # use starmap to map multiple arguments onto process
    p.starmap(func=run_process, iterable=zip(tasks, seeds))
```

Result:

> Task number 0 resulted in: 0.13436424411240122
>
> Task number 1 resulted in: 0.13436424411240122
>
> Task number 2 resulted in: 0.13436424411240122
>
> Task number 3 resulted in: 0.9560342718892494
>
> Task number 4 resulted in: 0.9560342718892494
>
> Task number 5 resulted in: 0.23796462709189137